# Read String From .strings file in XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to iOS and I have a .strings file in which I store a disclaimer that is viewed when my application is opened.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to call the "disclaimer" string from the disclaimer.strings file.

Help would be appreciated. Also, links to relevant pages are appreciated!

Comment: are you talking about localization strings?

Comment: Yes, I have a .strings file that contains my disclaimer and I am trying to use localization.

Comment: Are you sure you want to show a disclaimer? The HIG states that people can already view it in the App Store.

Comment: HIG? Are you confusing Disclaimer with EULA? I think they are different, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, first, rather than using a .string file, if there's only the disclaimer in it, then I would just use a txt file:

```
NSString * fName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"disclaimer" ofType:@"txt"];
if (fName) {
    self.disclaimer = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: fName];
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to do a localized version for each country, then just add it to your "Localizable.strings" file.  Your code is just:

```
self.disclaimer = NSLocalizedString(@"disclaimer", @"Disclaimer text for each country");
```

Then either use genstrings to collect all your Localizable strings, or create "Localizable.strings" (File\New\New File\ioS\Resource\Strings File), and then you can edit/add in the text:

```
"disclaimer" = "This is the English version of our disclaimer...";
```

Then you create a new language version of Localizable.strings and edit it with that country's disclaimer.

Comment: Awesome, this pretty much worked. I had to set the encoding, but other than that it was perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note that the "L" in Localizable.strings must be uppercase (the first occurrence in the answer is lowercase)... it's too small a change for an answer edit, but could be a source of confusion for some.

Answer (score 2):

The naming convention for Localizations expects a Localizable.strings file, under which you can then provide different language versions.

The best way is to start with using statements in your code like this one that returns the localized content for disclaimer :

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Disclaimer",@"Disclaimer")
```

The next step is to call genstrings from the command line on your classes directory:

```
genstrings -o en.lproj *.m
```

Comment: What if I wanted my own Disclaimer.strings file?

Comment: The Localizable.strings is the default way and therefor easier but using your own Disclaimer.strings file is possible too. In that case you will need to load your Disclaimer.strings file from the Application Bundle `NSString* disclaimerFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Disclaimer" ofType:@"strings"];` and then open the file and load the contents.