# popup view to display strings on a button click in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, popup, xcode4.2

In my application,i have some .strings files.And on a button click,which is on my main view,i have to display the contents taken from these .strings file and it should appear like a pop up view like the screen shot i have attached.How can i do this?Anyone have any helpful tutorials or a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make a view with these number of labels or textviews.and set label.text=corresponding strings if it is string only or set the content of the text view with the files.and hide the view in the view didload.and then present or unhide the view when the button click event.and then again hide it in the close button action.

Answer (score 1):

if the string is short, use the

```
[btn setTitle:@"string" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

if the string is long ,u can add a UIImageView on the btn.

Answer (score 1):

Just refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6498257/1132951) answer for reading the .string file. Or make .txt files

then to show the strings just use labels as described by the @bugfinder and show/hide the view